# A JavaScript Quadratic Function to Simulate a Parabolic Curve

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, trigonometry

I am looking to generate an inverse Quadratic function with an array (which could be of any size). For example, rather than using a linear calculation to determine percentage complete (e.g. 3 / 10 * 100 = 30%), I want to use a quadratic curve so the percentage is flattened as more questions are answered, until all questions are answered (once all questions answered it should be 100% complete). By definition, a quadratic function has an exponent of 2 and the leading coefficient is negative when inverting the shape.

Notice the nice curve until the vertex in the following parabolic graph:

[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
const questions = ['q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4', 'q5', 'q6', 'q7', 'q8','q9','q10'];

function inverseQuad(x, len) {
 return ((x)**2) * 100;
}

inverseQuad(.1, 10); // 1%
inverseQuad(.2, 10); // 4%
inverseQuad(.3, 10); // 9%
...
inverseQuad(.9, 10); // 81%
inverseQuad(1, 10); //  100%
```

It is moving in the wrong direction. It is not inverted. How can I cleanup this quadratic function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way to write a quadratic that does this:

```js
const completion = (qs, total) => Math .round (100 * qs / total *  (2 - qs / total));

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] .forEach (x => {
  console .log (`${x} => ${completion (x, 10)}`)
})
```

This is essentially `100 * (1 - (1 - x)**2)`, where `x` is the actual completion fraction.  Obviously it would be simpler if the input was that fraction: `const completion = (x) => 100 * x * (2 - x)`.

But I do have to say, using this to make people feel better about their completion percentage seems a quite unfriendly lie.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for quadric, it looks a bit different. Most of the times these Curves are used for tweens, start, end and speed.

For example you see some graphs here: https://sole.github.io/tween.js/examples/03_graphs.html

Luckily they already programmed the scripts for these curves here: https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/blob/master/src/Tween.js

Look for Quadratic, you will find the following:

```
Quadratic: {
    In: function (k) {
        return k * k;
    },

    Out: function (k) {
        return k * (2 - k);
    },

    InOut: function (k) {
        if ((k *= 2) < 1) {
            return 0.5 * k * k;
        }
        return - 0.5 * (--k * (k - 2) - 1);

    }

},
```

I think this formula is what you are looking for, if not look at one of the other Graphs and find the corresponding formula.

Note: You need to have normalized values
Note: To inverse the output just do `1 - output`